# order by with fallback

Tags: mysql

I want to retrieve data with a simple SELECT statement and ORDER BY, but the ORDER BY should have a fallback.

That is: my records have a filed `name` and a field name `sortkey`:

```
CREATE TABLE company
    (`id` int, `name` varchar(10), `sortkey` varchar(10))
;

INSERT INTO company
    (`id`, `name`, `sortkey`)
VALUES
    (1, 'Azzz', ''),
    (2, 'Bzzz', ''),
    (3, 'Czzz', 'Aaa')
;
```

I'd like to get the result from a SELECT statement:

```
Czzz
Azzz
Bzzz
```

When I have a `sortkey`, use it. If not, use the field `name`.

Peudo code: `SELECT * FROM company ORDER BY name,sortkey (but prioritize the sortkey);`

Comment: Something like: `ORDER BY IF(sortKey != '', sortKey, name)`?  (Docs: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/control-flow-functions.html)

Comment: @RocketHazmat yes, looks exactly what I need. If you post this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest using the [`IF()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/control-flow-functions.html) to determine which field to use.

```
SELECT * FROM company ORDER BY IF(sortKey != '', sortKey, name)
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use order by(sort) by multiple column.

```
SELECT * FROM company ORDER BY sortkey, name;
```

Comment: Hmm.. this looks like it should work.  If so, it's better than my answer.

Comment: PO's requirement is "When I have a sortkey, use it. If not, use the field name." The counterexample for my solution is: if sortkey is not empty, it will sort by sortkey and name together. What PO wants is if sortkey is not empty, it will sort only by sortkey. In that case, my solution is not good enough.

Comment: The result of the statement is 1,2 and 3, but it should be 3,1, and 2.

Comment: @topskip Really? I think ORDER BY col1, col2 will use col1 as main and col2 as secondary.

Answer (score 1):

try this query

```
 SELECT * FROM  company

  ORDER BY CASE
  WHEN sortkey != '' THEN sortkey 
  WHEN sortkey = '' THEN name

  END
```